# What are the differences for polylines between iOs maps and android maps?

Tags: c#, android, objective-c, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I'm converting an iOs app in c# to create a multi-platform version with xamarin.forms. The app presents a map where there are a lot of polylines, created from different jsons of points (latitude and longitude). When a polyline "finish" another start seamlessly, even because the last point of a polyline is the first one of the next. When i use the same jsons to create the polylines in c#, they are discontinuos, giving an unwanted effect. How can i try to resolve this issue? I got a native android version of the app and it has the same problem of the multi-platform version. I'm not the author of the iOs code. Thanks for the help!

[image: ios version]

[image: xamarin.forms version]

This is objective-c code:

```
id resp =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tratta.polilinea options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        //NSLog(@"%@",resp);
        if([resp isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            NSArray *listatratte = (NSArray*)resp;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D* coords = malloc([listatratte count] * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));

            float diskkm = tratta.ini_km;

            for(int i = 0; i < [listatratte count]; i++)
            {
                id cordinate = [listatratte objectAtIndex:i];

                //Aggiungo offset
                float lineangle = atan2(tratta.ini_lat - tratta.end_lat, tratta.end_lon - tratta.ini_lon);
                //float halfGap = 0.0060;
                float halfGap = [self getOffsetStrade];
                float radians = 90/M_PI;

                float angleTop = 90/radians + lineangle;
                float topoffsetx = cos(angleTop)*halfGap;
                float topoffsety = sin(angleTop)*halfGap;

                float angleBottom = -90/radians + lineangle;
                float botoffsetx = cos(angleBottom)*halfGap;
                float botoffsety = sin(angleBottom)*halfGap;

                if([tratta.direzione isEqualToString:@"D"])
                {
                    CLLocationCoordinate2D punto = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[cordinate objectForKey:@"lat"]doubleValue]+topoffsetx, [[cordinate objectForKey:@"lon"]doubleValue]+topoffsety);
                    coords[i] = punto;
                }
                else
                {
                    CLLocationCoordinate2D punto = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[cordinate objectForKey:@"lat"]doubleValue]+botoffsetx, [[cordinate objectForKey:@"lon"]doubleValue]+botoffsety);
                    coords[i] = punto;
                }
            }
            MKPolyline *poly = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:[listatratte count]];
            if([tratta.direzione isEqualToString:@"D"])
            {
                poly.title = @"D";
            }
            else
            {
                poly.title = @"S";
            }
            free(coords);
```

this is c# code:

```
 private async Task DrawPolyline(List<Tuple<int,List<Model.Position>>> ListOfListPolylinePoints)
        {
            //IsIntoFiPiLi = false;

            if (Map.Polylines.Count > 0) RemovePolylines();

            foreach (var listOfPoints in ListOfListPolylinePoints)
            {
                var tratta = await RepositoryHelper.Instance.TratteRepository.GetItemAsync(listOfPoints.Item1);
                var polyline_to_draw = new Polyline();
                var points_polilyne = listOfPoints.Item2;
                for (var i = 0; i < points_polilyne.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    var lineAngle = Math.Atan2(points_polilyne[i].lat - points_polilyne[i + 1].lat,
                        points_polilyne[i + 1].lon - points_polilyne[i].lon);
                    var halfGap = GetOffsetStreet();
                    var radians = 90 / Math.PI;
                    var angleTop = 90 / radians + lineAngle;
                    var topoffsetx = Math.Cos(angleTop) * halfGap;
                    var topoffsety = Math.Sin(angleTop) * halfGap;
                    var angleBottom = -90 / radians + lineAngle;
                    var botoffsetx = Math.Cos(angleBottom) * halfGap;
                    var botoffsety = Math.Sin(angleBottom) * halfGap;

                    if (tratta.direzione == "D")
                        polyline_to_draw.Positions.Add(new Position(points_polilyne[i].lat + topoffsetx,
                            points_polilyne[i].lon + topoffsety));
                    else
                        polyline_to_draw.Positions.Add(new Position(points_polilyne[i].lat + botoffsetx,
                            points_polilyne[i].lon + botoffsety));
                }


                polyline_to_draw.StrokeColor = GetTrafficColor(tratta);
                polyline_to_draw.StrokeWidth = strokeWidth;

                Map.Polylines.Add(polyline_to_draw);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not understanding your question very well. The two screenshots of iOS and Android looks same. I can't figure out the difference and I does not see any discontinuos polylines. Also, can you please share a Minimal, Reproducible Example to reproduce the problem? Something like those points in `tratta.polilinea`.

Comment: Hi @JackHua-MSFT, if you see better under the label on map "Lastra a Signa" in the android version, you can see that there is a discontinuity between the two polylines. Analyzing better the code, i saw that if i take the polylines' points and i put in an hard way, it works as expected. So, i saw that when i deserialize points from the jsons containings the points, instead, there is some rounding of decimal figures, and I imagine that this is the real problem. So how can i avoid that Newtonsoft.Json rounds values taken from a json?

Comment: Ok, I saw the discontinuos polylines.You can have a try with below codes:   `var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings(); settings.FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal; var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, settings);` Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks, now it works as expected.

Comment: I post an answer with the code in the comment, can you please mark it so that we can help more people with same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can i avoid that Newtonsoft.Json rounds values taken from a
>   json?

You can set the `FloatParseHandling` to `Decimal` in the `JsonSerializerSettings`, here is the code example:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings(); 
settings.FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal;
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, settings);
```